# Failling when trying to destroy a data entry with Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

I have the following beforeSave function that should remove an entry if there is any with the same fbEventId. If the query dont find any entry it should return success too (new data to be saved).

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("FbEvent", function(request, response) { 
  var query = new Parse.Query("FbEvent");
  query.equalTo("fbEventId", request.object.get("fbEventId"));
  query.find({
    success: function(results){
      if (results.length>0){
          var toRemove = results[0];
          console.log(toRemove);
          toRemove.destroy({
            success: function(toRemove){
              response.success();
            }, error: function(toRemove, error){
              response.error("Failed when destroying existing entry.");
            }
          });
      } else {
      response.error();}
    }, error: function(error){
      response.error("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

This is returning the following log:

```
 I2015-01-04T17:46:43.884Z] v158: before_save triggered for FbEvent
  Input: {"original":null,"update":{"locationFbId":"locationId","startDate":"2014-12-25T00:30:00-0200","fbEventId":"1590722614482003","fbEventName":"O Beco Invade a Cidade Baixa! | Open Bar de Natal"}}
  Result: Validation failed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this result is coming because

```
response.error()
```

is being called with no arguments. Your issue is that you're calling response.error() when you really want to call response.success(). See below:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("FbEvent", function(request, response) { 
  var query = new Parse.Query("FbEvent");
  query.equalTo("fbEventId", request.object.get("fbEventId"));
  query.find({
    success: function(results){
      if (results.length>0){
          // This block here will remove only the first conflicting entry, if you want to simply not save this entry, then user response.error("Entry with this id exists, canceling save");
          var toRemove = results[0];
          console.log(toRemove);
          toRemove.destroy({
            success: function(toRemove){
              response.success();
            }, error: function(toRemove, error){
              response.error("Failed when destroying existing entry.");
            }
          });
      } else {
      // There are 0 elements in the resulting array, so we do want to save, meaning we should return success
      response.success();}
    }, error: function(error){
      response.error("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: No problem! It's an easy mistake to make